Why did standard built-in objects Function and Object become each other's instance? And how is this implemented?
The following code snippet shows Function and Object become each other's instance.
// below code snippet shows Function is an instance of Object
Function instanceof Object;  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(Function.prototype, Object);  // true
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object);  // true

// below code snippet shows Object is an instance of Function
Object instanceof Function;  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(Object.prototype, Function);  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Function);  // true

// below code snippet means both Function.__proto__ and Object.__proto__ reference the same object in memory
Object.is(Function.__proto__, Object.__proto__);  // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object);  // true
Function.constructor.prototype === Object.constructor.prototype;  // true
Function.__proto__ === Object.__proto__;  // true

And also, Function MDN web page and Object MDN web page, shows Function and Object inherit each other?
screenshot of Function MDN web page
screenshot of Object MDN web page
In my opinion, an instance is initialized/generated by a class, but a class should not initialized/generated by an instance.
I know that OOP in js is prototype-based OOP, and it would be a little different from traditional OOP(like python OOP), I still can't understand Why did Function and Object become each other's instance? is this kinda wired in logic?
And another question: how to implement that AClass and BClass become each other's instance?
Is the following example correct?
// example for making `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` become each other's instance

class MyClass1 { constructor() {} }
class MyClass2 { constructor() {} }
Object.setPrototypeOf(MyClass1, MyClass2.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(MyClass2, MyClass1.prototype);

// below code snippet shows MyClass1 is an instance of MyClass2
MyClass1 instanceof MyClass2;  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(MyClass2.prototype, MyClass1);  // true
MyClass2.prototype.isPrototypeOf(MyClass1);  // true

// below code snippet shows MyClass2 is an instance of MyClass1
MyClass2 instanceof MyClass1;  // true
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(MyClass1.prototype, MyClass2);  // true
MyClass1.prototype.isPrototypeOf(MyClass2);  // true


"is this kinda wired in logic?" not at all because you're not starting off in an empty  "primary universe" sort of situation. In a language like C, for example, you start from scratch and you have to build up all the entries in your universe. So, you can't really have a chicken and egg situation as you need one for the other. That's it. In JS, a lot of stuff just "magically" appears. You never need to manage or create them in your code. You're in a "secondary universe" which gets members from above, thus no logical inconsistency case - you get both a chicken and an egg at the same time

@VLAZ Very unique insights also a bit magical, pretty thanks.

It's not really unique, though. You have the same situation in other languages. Like Java which comes with many built-in things you can use. Like you can just create an application window in Java and you take it for granted that you'd get an application window. Then you get one OS-appropriate window (with other elements - buttons, scroll bars, etc) without having to manage all of the nitty-gritty yourself. You just take it for granted windows and buttons exist.

Also, the same thing can happen in C. Or any other language that starts with an empty universe by default. You can have some host-provided items or APIs or libraries that are "magic" in terms of "things that didn't originate from me". A lot of software development does rely on such magic. You're rarely starting from a completely empty space. Except many if you're doing embedded programming or microcontrollers and such, so there is literally not even a lot there. But if you're running the software in a desktop OS, you're likely not relying on direct access to each resource.
